# FHIR Sorting - How to find out which parameter to pass

Tags: azure, sorting, hl7-fhir, bluebutton

Team, I am using FHIR bluebutton for CMS data (Claims data) and
now I want to apply sorting in FHIR data
we are getting bundle of explanation of Benefit(EOB)

[image: This is the image I have taken reference of sorting]

https://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html#sort

I have tried passing date and status params in that _sort
but still not getting sorted data
and I am very much in confusion what to pass as a parameter
suppose I want to sort by ClaimNumber

what to pass, please help and suggest me

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a search parameter as input for the sorting. For example sorting on last updated date descending would look like this:

```
GET [base]/ExplanationOfBenefit?_sort=-_lastUpdated
```

I'm not familiar with which field of ExplanationOfBenefit would hold the ClaimNumber you mention, but if you mean the EOB identifier, the request could be this:

```
GET [base]/ExplanationOfBenefit?_sort=identifier
```

If you use the correct syntax, success will still depend on whether the server has implemented sorting on that parameter.

Comment: OK @mirjam thank you   , I got it now that how to pass the parameter to _Sort 
but any one can confirm that which  parameter's sorting is implemented and possible.
I have 4-5 columns in a grid to sort , some of them are amount column

Comment: That would be something to ask your server vendor. They will know the capabilities of their server.